# End of brake cable touches tire

Tags: road-bike, tire, brakes

On my Trek Domane SLR the end of the front brake cable touches the tire. It makes an enerving sound and I am a afraid it destroys my tire. I thought about using some tape, but that is not possible because of the moving brake arm. Is there any possibility to push the cable to the side without renewing the while cable?[image: here the cable]
[image: Without tire]

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, who replaced the cable? It's a perfectly understandable slip up if you did it at home (I've done worse and am very cautious when working on brakes so as not to risking having both out of action). If a bike shop did it I'd want to know how they react before using them again. Doing it is sloppy, missing it before giving it back is sloppy, and sloppy work on brakes is a red flag.

Comment: A new cable is cheap and easy to pull in, especially at the front and still better than any work around solution.Then cut it to the correct length so that the ferrule sits behind the brake shoe. If it was done at a shop I'd have them replace it. Sloppy work, I agree with @Chris H. BTW the bike looks rather new and the braking surface on the rim seems unused. If you got it like that from a shop take it back, complain and have them replace the cable. The bike is too expensive for a $1 bit to be unsuitable.

Comment: @Carel you're probably right. I'm used to diy/ make do and mend.

Comment: A dirty hack would be to cut the cable even shorter.  However there's an increased risk of it pulling through on a hard stop, plus adjustments are harder.  I'd do this to get some life out of the inner, before replacing it properly.    If it were the rear inner, I'd contemplate reusing it as the front inner on another bike.   But inners are probably the single cheapest consumable part on your bike, with a single cable costing under $2 US, or full front/back set of "performance" inner/outers/ferrules costing under $10. US from somewhere like wiggle.

Comment: It was not replaced, the bike is almost new!

Comment: @Criggie If a cable pulls through on a hard stop something else is wrong.  That clamp bolt should be *tight*  And I say that as someone who rides chrome rims + cheap brakes in the wet on one of my bikes (good pads though).

Comment: @OblTobl so the bike shop cut it too short when they built it up?  I've just bought a new bike, and taking it in to the shop will take a bit of planning (complicated commute, shop near work).  So I'd do something temporary and get them to sort it at the 6-week checkup that's included in the sale.

Comment: I will contact my dealer tomorrow and ask him to replace the cable(s). I bought the bike half a year ago and hope that this is just seen as included service. Carel is absolutely right with his comment that the bike was much to expensive to try to save now a little amount. Thanks for all the replies and your help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Chris H has the right idea. Eventually when you replace the brake cables leave it long so you can tuck it on the outside of the brake pad. For the time being i agree with Chris, do what you can to try and prevent it from rubbing because over time it will wear a groove in the tire if it hasn't already.

Here is an image from Trek`s website showing how they have it long and tucked to the side. Nice brakes but the cable routing leaves some to be desired in my opinion.

[image]

Answer (score 14):

It looks like it's been cut too short so can't be tucked out of the way.  But you may be able to cut it still shorter and use a smaller end cap/ferrule, or just part of one, or a blob of glue to stop the end fraying.

Bending the cable may work too -- you might not have enough length but a sharp bend away from the tyre might work.  Use longnose pliers.  This stopped my front derailleur cable irritating my leg, for example.

You're right to want to fix it -- metal rubbing on tyres isn't a good thing.

Comment: I really thought about many things...but not about using some glue. I will try out your tips. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not glue. Glue won't hold up as well as metal. I've used a cable butt-connector in a pinch, or part of one. Bending is also good, and I've done that too.

Comment: @MathieuK. Epoxy would do well, or hot glue.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the the other options here, you may try *extending* the cable, or at least pretending like you're extending the cable - get some metal tube or maybe even a stiff plastic and crimp/glue it to the metal ferrule at the current end of the cable, then you may be able to extend *that* long enough to keep the end away from the tire.

Comment: That is a cunning idea - Even a stiff piece of plastic tube could be sufficient.